# Transfer Mousedown from Slider1 to Slider2?

Tags: jquery

So my first slider #yw0 when it reaches value of > 195 then it will swap to tab 2 and i want to be able to bind the mousedown to #yw2 so the #yw2 slider will slide automatically without letting go of mouse.

As you can see i have trigger('mouseup') to stop the even on #yw0 from sliding anymore, how can i now make the #yw2 slide?

```
jQuery('#yw0').slider({
        'range': 'max',
        'min': 0,
        'max': 130,
        'slide': function(event, ui) {

            $("#Credit_Amount").val(ui.value);

            $("#AmountsDiv").text(GetAmount(ui.value));

            GenerateAdditionalPrecents(ui.value);

            RefreshValues();

            if (parseInt($("#AmountsDiv").text()) > "195") {
                $("#tab2").addClass("selected");
                $("#loan").addClass("hide");
                $("#tab1").removeClass("selected");
                $("#loan2").removeClass("hide");
                $('#yw0').trigger('mouseup');
            } else {
                $("#tab1").addClass("selected");
                $("#loan2").addClass("hide");
                $("#tab2").removeClass("selected");
                $("#loan").removeClass("hide");
            }

        },
        'value': 0
});
```

Comment: a jsfiddle may clarify your issue.

Comment: This is the link to my working app: http://dev4you.byethost15.com/Loan%20Calculator